# Setting a textbox default value from a related table

Tags: ms-access, vba, default-value

I'm self taught in access VBA and I've been trying to figure this one out for ages now but can't get it to work. Any advice would really be much appreciated.

I have a database with a `staff` table and a form `frmStaff` which is bound to this table. There is also a second table called `tblStages` which records the coaching stages each staff member has been on. These tables are related on the `staffID` field.

I am trying to add a textbox on the form which will display the current coaching stage for the staff member in the current record (I'm trying to avoid using a subform). I have set the default value for this textbox as below:

```
DLookup("[stage]", "[tblStages]", "[staffID] = '" & [Forms]![frmStaff]![txtStaffID] & "' AND isnull([endDate])")
```

There will only ever be 1 record for each staff member where the stage `endDate` is null. This Dlookup works perfectly in the vba editor but when I set it as the default value of the textbox it does not work. I expect this is because it tries to find the default value before the form is open and therefore the `txtStaffID` control is empty.

I hope I have explained  this problem properly. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be incredible grateful. Thank you

Comment: Why not set the value in VBA in form load?

Comment: Hi Fionnuala. Thanks for the reply. I probably should've mentioned this but the form view is continuous. Therefore the value of the textbox would have to be different for each record that is displayed

Comment: In that case, your best bet is a join.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance. I'm not entirely sure what that means. Do you mean an SQL query with a join clause? If so, would I be able to enter this query as the default value property?

Comment: This query would be the from's sours, this field would be a field in the query, and the textBox's control sours. Note to make sour the query [isn't read only](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)

Comment: marlan. You, my friend, are an absolute genius. This works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you would like to add this as an official answer, I will be sure to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a query named `qrfrmStaff`:

```
SELECT staff.*, tblStages.stage AS Stage 
FROM tblStages INNER JOIN staff on tblStages.staffID = staff.staffID  
WHERE tblStages.endDate Is Null
```

Have `qrfrmStaff` as `frmStaff` record source, and `stage` the textBox's control source.

Make sure the [query is not read only](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html)!

Comment: Have you checked that that will run in MS Access? For the most part, you need to specify join type.

Comment: Thanks fionnuala for your helpful comment! @Leroy, Please make sure actually it works, and the form runs nicely, before you accept the answer.

Comment: Fair point. I'd already written the query based on your comment above so didn't actually copy the code from your official answer. I'll be sure to double check it next time